# Enforce one describe per file

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, eslint, static-code-analysis

**The Story:**

We have a rather big test codebase with Protractor+Jasmine tests.

One of the current problems we have is that *some of the test/spec files contain more than one describe* which causes troubles from time to time - for example, when debugging tests one by one (or in batches) we use `fdescribe`/`fit`; and occasionally we don't notice that there are other `decribe`s in the same file at the bottom eventually leading to parts of the tests to be unintentionally skipped.

In other words, this is sort of a variation of "one assertion per test" type of a rule helping to keep the test codebase clean and "flat".

**The Question:**

Is there a way to prohibit having more than one `describe` per file? I am currently thinking about approaching it with static code analysis and `ESLint`, but I'm open to other solutions as well.

**Samples:**

Example of a violation:

```
describe("Test 1", function () {
    it("should do something", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});

describe("Test 2", function () {
    it("should do something else", function () {
        expect(false).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

If there is a single `describe` block, but it contains nested `describe`s, it should not be reported as a violation. In other words, this is okay to have:

```
describe("Test 1", function () {
    it("should do something", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    describe("Test 2", function () {
        it("should do something else", function () {
             expect(false).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What about nested describe blocks?

Comment: @jonrsharpe good question. Only top-level describes should be considered. Updated the question with some samples. Thanks!

Comment: static analysis is the way to go. You should contribute the rule to https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha . So that anyone else interested can also consume it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tricky part is flagging only describe blocks that are not nested, or "top-level" describes. Luckily, this is totally possible with ESLint!

ESLint "visits" the nodes two times while traversing the abstract syntax tree (AST, for short) of your JavaScript code: once while going **down** the tree, and another while going **back up**.
The tree is traversed depth first, so if for example you have 3 `describe` blocks in your code like this:

```
describe("Test 1", function () {
    it("should do something", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

    describe("Test 2", function () {
        it("should do something else", function () {
             expect(false).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});

describe("Test 3", function () {
    it("should do something", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The nodes would be visited in the following order:

`enter "Test 1"` -> `enter "Test 2"` -> `exit "Test 2"` -> `exit "Test 1"` -> `enter "Test 3"` -> `exit "Test 3"`

That means we just have to keep track of all the `describe` calls in a stack while going "down" a subtree, then pop them one at a time while going "up" that subtree. if while going up there is only one node left to pop from the stack, then that node is a "top-level" `describe`.

At the end, if we found more than on "top-level" describe, then our rule should report an error. I whipped up a small working prototype for you: https://astexplorer.net/#/3vMUwQjfpD/2

Comment: That's almost a complete rule as is, I'll make a custom rule out of it and post in a separate answer. Not sure, if this rule should be a part of [`eslint-plugin-mocha`](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha) or [`eslint-plugin-jasmine`](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine) (this one is not well maintained at the moment, unfortunately) cause there is probably not much of a demand for this kind of narrow use case. Thanks so much!

Comment: The rule is now the part of `eslint-plugin-mocha`!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @vitorbal's sample code for the rule, the [pull request](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/pull/105) with the new [`max-top-level-suites` rule](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha/blob/master/docs/rules/max-top-level-suites.md) is now merged into and is a part of [`eslint-plugin-mocha`](https://github.com/lo1tuma/eslint-plugin-mocha) ESLint plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [no-restricted-syntax rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax).

The selector that you want to use is: `Program > ExpressionStatement[expression.type='CallExpression'][expression.callee.type='Identifier'][expression.callee.name='describe'] ~ ExpressionStatement[expression.type='CallExpression'][expression.callee.type='Identifier'][expression.callee.name='describe']`

Complete example:

```json
    "no-restricted-syntax": [2,
      {
        "selector": "Program > ExpressionStatement[expression.type='CallExpression'][expression.callee.type='Identifier'][expression.callee.name='describe'] ~ ExpressionStatement[expression.type='CallExpression'][expression.callee.type='Identifier'][expression.callee.name='describe']",
        "message": "Only one top level describe per test file"
      }
    ],
```